# How to override JS component file used in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, uicomponent

I would like to add my own JS to this file to add a little customization to the checkout in Magento 2.

```
app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js
```

I tried copying it to my theme folder but it Magento doesn't pick it up, it still uses the file above.

```
app/design/frontend/Holy/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/shipping-address/list.js
```

**How can I override this file?**  I thought I could have easily overriden this in my theme?

Do I need to create a module for it?  And in it's `/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` file add something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="address-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Holy_MyModule/js/view/shipping-address/list</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then I guess I can create my JS file in

```
app/code/Holy/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js
```

But how can I make sure it picks up everything from Magento_Checkout?  Is there something I need to add at the beginning of the file, in `define` block, `Component.extend` function, or the child functions like `initChildren`

Answer (score 5):

If you need override js in your theme, just copy to your theme with corresponding path with same name

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme-name\Magento-Checkout\web\js\view\shipping-address\list.js

For extend component in module

1. Create requirejs-config.js in  `Vendor\Module-Name\view\frontend`

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/list': {
                'Vnecoms_Demo/js/view/shipping-address/list': true
            }
        }
    }

};
```

2. Create Vnecoms_Demo/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js Follow name is your choice. 
Copy from original and modify with your demands

Ex:

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2017 Vnecoms, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*global define*/
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (ListShipping) {
        return ListShipping.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/list',
                rendererTemplates: [],
                isExtend: true,
                testVariable: 1
            },

            initialize: function () {
                console.log('my custom');
                this._super()
                    .initChildren();

            }
        });
    }
});
```

To apply new changes

```
rm pub/static/frontend/
rm pub/static/_requirejs/
rm var/cache/
rm var/generation/
```